# Propel paginate with newly added items (setting offset manually or sth.)

Tags: php, propel, offset, pagination

I have a page where I render items from my database in reversed chronological order. Last added item is the first item on top of the page.

I use infinite scrolling, so everytime the user hits the bottom, I send pagenumber and resultcount to my server. There I use propel paginate to get the next page.

The problem is, when an user adds a new item on the page it will be added to my database and is the first item on page 1 in my results. So all other results are shifted by 1 position.
Is there a way to tell propel that it should start at offset+1 to ignore the new added element?

A little example:

I have 5 items per page. In this example every item has only a number, so on the page you can see 1,2,3,4,5. Now, a user adds the item 0. My database results w/o pagination is now:
0,1,2,3,4,5 because the new item is added. Now the user hits the bottom of the page and the pagination has the attributes page = 2, items per page = 5 and I will get 5,6,7,8,9. Now my page renders the 5 again. If I could say propel that the initial offset should start after the first item, the result would be ok.

Comment: This was asked a while ago, did you end up solving this issue? I'd be interested to know how. If so, you should answer your own question and then accept the answer!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have a good solution for the problem that fits to the question.

Comment: What about adding a filter to the criteria with the current time, using Propel's timestampable you could limit results to when the search was initially created... I'll try to work up an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, haven't tried the code myself, but you could add a timestamp to the search criteria and pass it in with the paging so that all search results are restricted to records created before the current search began:

```
<?php
$page = (isset($_GET['page']))?$_GET['page']:1;
$timeFilter = (isset($_GET['time']))?$_GET['time']:date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

$posts = PostQuery::create()
  ->filterByCreatedAt($timeFilter, Criteria::LESS_THAN)
  // add other filters as necessary
  ->paginate($page, $limit);
// Obviously there is a lot of other things to include, just an example...
?>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Paging Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id='results'>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post) {

      echo "<li>".$post->getTitle()."</li>";

    } ?>
  </ul>

  <div id='paging'>
    <?php
    if (!$pager->isFirstPage()) {
      echo "<a href='thisFile.php?page=".$pager->getPreviousPage()."&time=".$timeFilter."'>Previous Page</a>";
    }

    // may want to add a page list here...

    if (!$pager->isLastPage()) {
      echo "<a href='thisFile.php?page=".$pager->getNextPage()."&time=".$timeFilter."'>Next Page</a>";
    }

    ?>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, do let me know if it works for you - or if you have to tweak it; I have a couple projects where I may use this.

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works for add but not for delete. This is not a good way of achieving this. If you can pass the start index with number of records you wont face any issue like this above as you can always compose the index by looking at the records you have. This can be achieved using DB level. However I am not sure whether propel supports that.